# clickDatePicker Function Forces Chrome to Refresh Page

Tags: 2013, datepicker

Surely other SP 2013 users have encountered this one. This is a bug specific to Chrome which causes a web part form page to refresh when a user attempts to use Sharepoint's out-of-the-box datepicker for date fields. I'm trying to find a workaround, as Chrome tends to be the most used browser in my office.

Some people on the Technet board were discussing it in this thread:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/afb45da0-38a2-44b8-b451-e7c93a0a54dc/calendars-in-chrome-cause-page-refresh-which-casues-the-page-the-calendar-is-on-to-scroll-back-up-to

One suggestion was to disable "inline editing" under Chrome, but I'm not sure what they mean.

Comment: Look at the answer from: [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116399/sharepoint-datepicker-jumps-to-top-in-chrome/150904#150904][1]


  [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116399/sharepoint-datepicker-jumps-to-top-in-chrome/150904#150904